# InfoPlist.strings vs a global.h for constants

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, info-plist

If I want to declare a constant string (not necessarily changing based on language) that can be used in multiple `.m` files should I do that in my InfoPlist.strings or should I create a separate `global.h` file and use `#define`?

The research I've done makes me thing `global.h` is the way to go but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what type of constant you need. For a simple string constant, using a `.strings` file has an advantage in that it doesn't need to re-compile the binary to have the values available inside the app, on the other hand, makes it easier for a hacker to modify.

Using a `.h` to store constants is better if you want to store numerics, as parsing an integer from a string is no small task.

Most of the time, I would say that a `.h` is better, but beware of pitfalls of using one! You cannot take an address of a constant in a `.h` (which normally you don't have to use), and comparing a string with `==` and a constant is a no-no.

Comment: Thanks.  When would I use the InfoPlist.strings file?  Is it just for strings that will change based on the applications language?

Comment: @JMax if you were to use a strings file for constants, definitely put them into another strings file, not `InfoPlist.strings`, maybe call it `Constants.strings`. Then, you would read those strings using `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` inside your application.

Comment: Ok. When do you we use InfoPlist.strings?

Comment: @JMax Almost never. if you want to use a strings file as a configuration, use a different strings file. Only use `InfoPlist.strings` if you need to localize something in `Info.plist`. I'm sorry, I thought I made that clear.